# Error Iterating over Join Query results using Peewe (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, peewee

I am not able to iterate through my query as I would like using Peewee

**Those are the related Objects in Models.py**

```
class Conversation(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.AutoField(unique=True, index=True)
    creation_date = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    contact_id = ForeignKeyField(Contact, backref='conversation')
    launch_id = ForeignKeyField(Launch, backref='conversation')
    request_data = peewee.TextField(null=True)
    status = peewee.TextField(null=True)
```

```
class Contact(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.AutoField(unique=True, index=True)
    uuid = peewee.CharField(default=shortuuid.uuid, index=True)
    whatsapp_phone = peewee.CharField(index=True, default='')
    status = peewee.CharField(default='init') 
    conversationId = peewee.CharField(null=True)
```

Here's how I am trying to iterate:

```
for conversation in Conversation.select().where(Conversation.launch_id == str(launch_id)):
    print(conversation.contact.id)
```

And this is the error that I a getting:

```
print(conversation.contact.id)
AttributeError: 'Conversation' object has no attribute 'contact'
```

I've tried to change the way I do my query:

```
query = Conversation.select(Contact).join(Contact).where(Conversation.launch_id == str(launch_id))
```

But I get the exact same error if I iterate in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are, for some reason, trying to access `.contact` when you've named your foreign-key `.contact_id`. The peewee docs are clear about foreign key naming, but you want this:

```
class Conversation(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.AutoField(unique=True, index=True)
    creation_date = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    # Data will be stored in a column named "contact_id":
    contact = ForeignKeyField(Contact, backref='conversations')
    # Data will be stored in a column named "launch_id":
    launch = ForeignKeyField(Launch, backref='conversations')
    request_data = peewee.TextField(null=True)
    status = peewee.TextField(null=True)
```

This allows:

```
query = (Conversation
         .select()
         .where(Conversation.launch == str(launch_id)))
for conversation in query:
    # Access the underlying foreign-key value.
    print(conversation.contact_id)
```

Or, if you intend to access other fields on the `Contact`:

```
query = (Conversation
         .select(Conversation, Contact)
         .join(Contact)
         .where(Conversation.launch == str(launch_id)))
for conversation in query:
    # We now have a "full" Contact instance we can access efficiently:
    print(conversation.contact.id)
```

Please read the docs:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#lists-of-records
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#foreignkeyfield

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your amazing contribution to the community. I will make sure I review all the docs that you've attached.